# Enlarging a Specific Area of Clickable Nested Text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native

Hi all,

In my app I have a list of articles, and inside of it, at the very end of each body of text, a "reference" indicator that is a clickable bit of text that opens the corresponding URL to that article on the web. Unfortunately this clickable text is so small that the users cannot tap on it easily.

I want to make the text larger (or increase the hit / tap area) so it can be more-easily tapped.

Here is my view hierarchy:

```
<View style={this.props.style}> 
 <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {this.paragraphTextHere()}
  <Text onPress={this.performAction.bind(this) style={styles.sourceText}>[<Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>{sourceId} </Text> ]
  </Text> 
  </Text> 
 </View>
```

The goal is to create some text that ends with [1] or [2] (similar to the citations/references you'd see in a book)

I tried adding non-breaking spaces (nbsp) to increase the "hit area" but it's being cut off in some instances when it renders. I know nbsp is a bad idea, and here is an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dpel.png

Unfortunately I've tried changing both padding and margin properties on the both the inner and outer Text views, but nothing changes--it's like the Text component is immune to any change from padding/margin.

How can I add this extra touch area to the text (to make the hit area bigger), without
getting the text cut off or making the entire paragraph larger? Is there another approach I could take?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: why not try `font-size` :)

Comment: Thanks @windmaomao that would work but is there a way to increase and pad the area around it to increase the "hit box"? So I can keep the text about the same, but increase the tappable region?

Comment: i'm not familiar with mobile, in theory all layout element should appreciate padding and margin. So take a look at the dock, is there anything can hold the Text?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text you want to be pressable into a `Pressable` component and then increase the tappable area by using the `hitSlop` props.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/pressable#hitslop

E.g

```
<Text style={styles.textStyle}>
your text...
    <Pressable hitSlop={{ top: 5, left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 }} onPress={this.performAction.bind(this)}>
        <Text style={styles.sourceText}>
          [<Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>{sourceId}</Text>]
        </Text>
    </Pressable>
</Text>
```

Comment: Gabriel thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I am using React 0.59 and I believe Pressable is only available starting in React Native v0.63.  Is this correct? If so, any other ideas? Also, is it a tough upgrade? thanks!

Comment: @gabriel-donadel-dallagnol thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: @NullHypothesis you can use `touchablewithoutfeedback` which also supports `hitSlop`

Comment: Hope this fixes your problem

Comment: @gabriel-donadel-dallagnol in theory if I did a higher value like hitslop of 15, should I be able to click the whitespace 15 pixels (or a little less) from the "link" and it should still work in the emulator? If I tap on the white space nothing happens.